# How to avoid T-SQL error: conversion from type DBNull to type String is not valid

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, dbnull

I used the following T-SQL to insert data to an application which is build by C# Some records works fine but some give the error below.

[image]

```
INSERT INTO [MITESTCO].[dbo].[MIQSUP] ([itemId], [suplProdCode], [suplId])  
    SELECT
        [itemId], [suplId], [suplProdCode]  
    FROM 
        [table 28]   
    WHERE  
        [itemId] NOT IN (SELECT [itemId] FROM [MIQSUP]);
```

> See the end of this message for details on invoking  just-in-time
>   (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.
>
> ************** Exception Text ************** System.InvalidCastException: Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type
>   'String' is not valid.    at
>   Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToString(Object
>   Value)    at
>   MISys.Client.MIUltraDataGrid.MIUltraDataGrid.MIUltraDataGrid_InitializeRow(Object
>   sender, InitializeRowEventArgs e)    at
>   Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.InitializeRowEventHandler.Invoke(Object
>   sender, InitializeRowEventArgs e)    at
>   Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGrid.OnInitializeRow(InitializeRowEventArgs
>   e)    at
>   Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGrid.FireEvent(GridEventIds id,
>   EventArgs e)    at
>   Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGrid.FireInitializeRow(InitializeRowEventArgs
>   e)    at
>   Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridRow.FireInitializeRow()    at
>   Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.RowsCollection.FireInitializeRow(IList
>   rows)    at
>   Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.RowsCollection.InitNonGroupByRows(IList
>   fireInitializeRowOnTheseRows)    at
>   Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.RowsCollection.SyncRowsHelper(IList
>   boundList)    at
>   Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.RowsCollection.SyncRows()    at
>   Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.RowsCollection.EnsureNotDirty()    at
>   Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.RowsCollection.GetEnumerator()    at
>   MISys.Client.MIUltraDataGrid.MIUltraDataGrid.RefreshGrid()    at
>   MISysForms.MIDetailsTemplate.RefreshGrids(Control myparent)    at
>   MISysForms.MIDetailsTemplate.RefreshGrids(Control myparent)    at
>   MISysForms.MIDetailsTemplate.RefreshGrids(Control myparent)    at
>   MISysForms.MIDetailsTemplate.RefreshGrids(Control myparent)    at
>   MISysForms.MIDetailsTemplate.RecordChanged()    at
>   MISysForms.MIItemDetails.RecordChanged()    at
>   MISysForms.MIDetailsTemplate.GetPreviousRecord()    at
>   MISysForms.MIDetailsTemplate.UltraToolbarsManager1_ToolClick(Object
>   sender, ToolClickEventArgs e)    at
>   Infragistics.Win.UltraWinToolbars.UltraToolbarsManager.OnToolClick(ToolClickEventArgs
>   e)    at
>   ....

Comment: How about sharing the actual code you are using?

Comment: If you click on details does it tell you more specifically where that error is coming from?

Comment: @TimFreese yes i add at the bottom of my questions

Comment: Here is the problem. You posted a dotnet error message and the only code you have shown us is a query. You can't get that error message from sql. You need to show us the dotnet code if you want any real chance at finding  solution.

Comment: @SeanLange sorry, I dont have access to the `.Net` part

Comment: Well the error is in your dotnet code. It is apparently trying to display these rows and crashes because it can't handle a NULL. You will either need to fix the dotnet side of things or modify your data so there are not NULLs in there. I would push pretty hard that fixing the code is the best approach. Modifying data to accommodate poorly written code is not a good habit to get into.

Answer (score 2):

Ask your datarow if the value isn't null, for example, then you can cast it fine:

```
object Value = dataRow[columnName];
if (Value != DBNull.Value)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the above answer or if you dont have access to the code, change your SELECT to insert blank instead of null's, assuming you have a SQL Server

```
INSERT INTO [MITESTCO].[dbo].[MIQSUP] ([itemId], [suplProdCode], [suplId])  
SELECT
    IsNull([itemId],''), IsNUll([suplId], ''), ISNull([suplProdCode],'')  
FROM 
    [table 28]   
WHERE  
    [itemId] NOT IN (SELECT [itemId] FROM [MIQSUP]);
```

Answer (score 0):

One of your columns is returning NULL value and as indicated in stack trace, calling ToString() function raise that error. You can rewrite your SELECT statement using TSQL, ISNULL function.

```
INSERT INTO [MITESTCO].[dbo].[MIQSUP] ([itemId], [suplProdCode], [suplId])  
SELECT
    [itemId], [suplId], ISNULL([suplProdCode],'') as suplProdCode
FROM 
    [table 28]   
WHERE  
    [itemId] NOT IN (SELECT [itemId] FROM [MIQSUP]);
```